# PowerMockito returns null when mock constrtuctor is defined for any arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I've been trying to figure out what's the deal with PowerMockito's constructor mocking. My code is similar to the following:

```
public void testConstruction() {
    whenNew(Account.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mock(Account.class));
    assertNotNull(new Account("name")); //fails
}
```

I'm not really sure where else to look for to find what's causing this issue. With the above stubbing code, PowerMockito will only return the object created by `mock(Account.class)` when I call the constructor with *no arguments*; it's acting as if I stubbed it using `withNoArguments()`. I'm sure that my test class is set up correctly because the following code passes:

```
public void testConstruction() {
    whenNew(Account.class).withArguments("name").thenReturn(mock(Account.class));
    assertNotNull(new Account("name")); //passes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue. withAnyArguments doesn't behave as expected if the class being mocked has more than one constructor. In my case the class mocked with whenNew had 2 constructors and I would always get null when new instance of this class was created. https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/891 gave some hint and I switched to using withArguments.